# How To Block Websites in Ubuntu?

Tags: websites

I have added a site in my hosts file but its not working, please view the pics.

My Hosts file

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       Ubuntu.local    Ubuntu
 127.0.0.1       dailymotion.com *.dailymotion.com http://www.dailymotion.com*
 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
 ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**As added in hosts file the site is blocked**
[image]

**Copy Paste The Video Link ....Site is not Block**
[image]

**How do i block each and every link that has http://dailymotion.com/**

I have tried with 0.0.0.0 dailymotion.com to hosts file, nothing work..But in Windows 7 & Windows 8 its working perfectly

**Not interested in weird iptables commands**

Thanks

Thanks to [Achu](https://askubuntu.com/users/9701/achu)

[image]

Comment: You have to look where the video is coming from. My guess would by youtube. You probably want to use a web proxy such as privoxy or squid, but configuration can be a bit complicated. Hard to know without knowing where the video is from (Go under Tools -> Web Developer -> Page source and see if you can determine where the video is coming from). Also know that you can call content by server_name.com or ip address. If the content is called by ip address your hosts file will not work.

Comment: 1st of the duplicate question is very old and i want to block it , @bodhi.zazen ok let me check and update ...thanks all

Comment: why the same stuff is working in windows 7 and in windows 8 ??? hosts file

Comment: youtube is already blocked in my country

Comment: Globs and URLs do not work in `/etc/hosts`. Also, you do not want to list the same IP multiple times, with different domains. You want to use a firewall to block sites, and something like `gufw` might help you configure it.

Comment: @XxxXxx please try this way `127.0.0.1 www.dailymotion.com`
`127.0.0.1 dailymotion.com` `127.0.0.1 *.dmcdn.net` `127.0.0.1 dmcdn.net` put them on each line. i saw videos come from `dmcd.net`

Comment: @XxxXxx good. i will put that as an answer.

Comment: ok i m waiting....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please put this way

```
127.0.0.1 www.dailymotion.com 
127.0.0.1 dailymotion.com 
127.0.0.1 *.dmcdn.net 
127.0.0.1 dmcdn.net
```

I can see that dailymotion video's comes from `dmcd.net`