# How to enable access to websites

Tags: websites

How to block a website from Ubuntu, that the user can never access to that web site, please?

For example, if I want to block `www.google.com`, how do I to enable the access to it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As in http://askubuntu.com/questions/285506/how-to-block-websites-in-ubuntu

Comment: @hakermania, I haven't seen into the links you have provided any solution to the question :/ Can please just write how do I to enable access to some websites from Ubuntu 14.04, please ?

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates @AmurayuYukiko

Comment: I marked this question as too broad as there are tons of options for blocking access from a hosts file to a proxy (squid) to your firewall to your router and probably a few others I did not mention.

Answer (score 0):

access to websites is not under the control of the operating system. You can block applications, but not websites.

You can access (and block, for that matter) **only** by the use of "browsers." The one you used to post this question here, yes.

Suppose it's Mozilla Firefox. You can look for extensions that can do the trick for you. I would not go fishing for them, but I used to have an extension that would "blacklist" websites so that they **never** open.

If you don't use the browser, the website won't open, you understand that, right? So, the trick lies in the browser. Please post a similar question to the support forums of the particular browser(s) you use to access the internet and want to block sites from.

Comment: That is not really try. I suppose it depends on what you mean by "operating system". I most certainly can block access to servers with a firewall or proxy server. For example ufw/itables. `iptables -A OUTUPT -d 1.2.3.4 -j REJECT` will block all traffic to 1.2.3.4 . google search squid ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking some time to read the official documentation regarding Parental Controls at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls as it discusses some of the options available to you.